# Getting Type identity of Swift type by name

Tags: swift, reflection, metatype

I'm trying to use a type identity as a key in a dictionary, but I'm having trouble writing the declaration. In C#, I would use something like this:

```
Type theType = typeof(MyCoolClass);
```

It seems like in Swift I want to use [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) - according to the docs, this function returns a `Metaclass` object, but when I try to use this type, I get:

> Type Metatype not found

```
protocol DependencyResolver {
     func getObject<T>(type: Metatype, contract: String?) -> T?
     func getAllObjects<T>(type: Metatype, contract: String?) -> T?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Metatype` is actually a *generic* argument of the [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) function (i.e., not a nominal type). The dynamic type returned is a *concrete* metatype (`T.Type`).

For instance, try using `Any.Type` instead ;)